# Lua function acting weird for some reason

Tags: loops, math, random, lua, while-loop

I'm trying to do a function in Lua which will randomly choose two numbers, and if their remainder is 0 and if their division result is smaller than 10 it will return these numbers. For example, the function should return 10 and 5, 20 and 4, etc.

Here's the code:

```lua
local num1, num2= math.random(1,100), math.random(1,10)

while ( (num1/num2 > 10 or num1/num2 < 1) and num1 % num2 ~= 0 ) do
    num1, num2= math.random(1,100), math.random(1,10)
end
print( num1 .. "  ".. num2 )
```

But for some reason it just returns me values such as **20** and **9**, although it runs trough the "while" loop... any idea why it happens or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic in the condition is wrong. If **either** `num1/num2 > 10 or num1/num2 < 1` **or** `num1 % num2 ~= 0`, the loop continues to find the next random values.

```
while ( (num1/num2 > 10 or num1/num2 < 1) and num1 % num2 ~= 0 ) do
```

should be:

```
while num1/num2 > 10 or num1/num2 < 1 or num1 % num2 ~= 0  do
--                                    ^^
```